# What happened to the "New Event" button in the mobile app Events screen?

Tags: mobile, event, button, app

My users are complaining that the "New Event" button has disappeared from the Events screen in the mobile app.

[image: Screen shot]

As far as I know we are using the standard Salesforce mobile app. I haven't done anything for it or with it (I don't use it myself).

Anyway: how can I make this button visible again? The hamburger menu just gives access to other screens, not to "New" actions.

I saw in the Event page layout that "New Event" was absent from the mobile actions and that "Poll" had been added. I added "New Event" and removed "Poll". No difference. I cleared the cache of the Android Salesforce app. Still no difference.

Just to experiment a bit: I updated the image that is used when starting the app. The app now displays the new image, I didn't have to empty any cache for that. So I know that the app is using the most recent data from the Salesforce configuration. I just have to figure out where the switch for the "New Event" button is located.

Comment: Possibly a silly question: Does the user as permission to create a new event, BTW the screen you're looking at is calendar tab on desktop lightning UI,

Comment: @Raul Perhaps it is also the calendar tab on desktop lightning UI, but I took a screenshot of my Android Salesforce app, of the Events screen. I am sysadmin, so I have permission to create events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Event button can be added or removed from Setup > Object Manager > Activity > Search Layout > List View

[image]

Comment: Great, this is indeed the solution. Mystery: the list view hadn't been touched in almost three years! But the users complained about a disappearing "New Event" button. So something must have happened, outside of the view. Anyway, it's fixed, the button is visible now! Thanks!